# Last query fired on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to know the last query that was fired on mySQL server, or the host it was fired from.
Any better way to do it?

Comment: Are you interested only in MySQL, or in MS SQL Server also?

Comment: mySQL only. Removed other tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since enabling logging of all queries will kill performance, you can create a proxy and keep the last query there. Or if you can afford changing the application code, alter the DB layer in a way that it stores the last executed query in memory (memcached for example)

Answer (score 2):

SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE'

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'

look to table mysql.general_log